# How to get data from server-side from nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I have error from my coding here:

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
        const httpResponse = await axios.get("/users");
        setUser(httpResponse.data)
        setId(httpResponse.data.id)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
    }, [])
    const firstname = String(user.targetFirstname);
```

here my code from server-side :

```
const db = require("../models")
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const getUser = async (req, res) => {
    const targetId = Number(req.user.id)
    const targetUser = await db.User.findOne({ where: { id: targetId } });
    if (!targetUser) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Id is wrong" });
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Get data completed",
            targetFirstname: targetUser.firstname,
            targetLastname: targetUser.lastname,
            targetEmail: targetUser.email,
            targetPassword: targetUser.password
        })
    }
}
```

I coding it in
nextjs, expressjs, antd, axios, mysql

I new in Nextjs and Reactjs I created medium,blog-clone to be myfullstack project.
I want to fetch user data from server-side that I create but it look like not working but if I console.log(user) in my terminal is show empty array but in console browser it show correctly.
**I just want Data to show in antd.form to be initialValues** but some how it is not worked

I try to chat with chatGPT3.5 but result that can't fixed my error

P.S. I just newbie sorry if my coding it look not clean